# The div is having double click problem after the first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

When clicking on each div it should increase in size, add another paragraph and close the other div if its opened, like a card.

It's working but I'm having to click twice to open it after the second click and I wanted it to work with just one click.

When I click one time in the first div it opens as expected, then I click on the second div and it also opens as expected, but then when I click in the first div again I end up having to click it twice to open.

```js
$('.promoItemAlimento').on('click', function() {
  if (!$(this).data('clicked')) {
    //do your stuff here if the button is not clicked
    $(this).removeClass('card-ativo1');
    $(".promoItemAlimento-naoativo").css("display", "none");
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
  } else {
    //do your stuff here if the button is clicked
    $(this).toggleClass('card-ativo1');
    $(".promoItemAlimento-naoativo").css("display", "block");
    $(this).data('clicked', false);
  }
});

$('.promoItemTreino').on('click', function() {
  if (!$(this).data('clicked')) {
    //do your stuff here if the button is not clicked
    $(this).removeClass('card-ativo2');
    $(".promoItemTreino-naoativo").css("display", "none");
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
  } else {
    //do your stuff here if the button is clicked
    $(this).toggleClass('card-ativo2');
    $(".promoItemTreino-naoativo").css("display", "block");
    //closes other card
    $(".promoItemAlimento-naoativo").css("display", "none");
    $(".promoItemAlimento").removeClass("card-ativo1")
    $(this).data('clicked', false);
  }
});
```

```css
.contentPromos {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.promoItemAlimento,
.promoItemTreino {
  height: 390px;
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f7afaf;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.promoItemAlimento-naoativo,
.promoItemTreino-naoativo {
  display: none;
}

.card-ativo1,
.card-ativo2 {
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="contentPromos">
  <div class="promoItemAlimento" data-clicked="true">
    <h3>Plano Alimentar individualizado</h3>
    <p>Tenha consultas mensais com a nutricionista para montar planos alimentares de acordo com suas necessidades, preferências e objetivos. </p>
    <div class="promoItemAlimento-naoativo">
      <p>Tenha consultas mensais com a nutricionista para montar planos alimentares de acordo com suas necessidades, preferências e objetivos. </p><br><br>
      <a class="contentPromos-btn" href="#" type="submit" onclick="vai()">EU QUERO RESULTADOS</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="promoItemTreino" data-clicked="true">
    <h3>Treinos personalizados</h3>
    <p>Tenha também planos de exercícios adaptados à sua rotina e de acordo com suas atividades de preferência, para realizar quando e onde quiser. </p>
    <div class="promoItemTreino-naoativo">
      <p>Tenha também planos de exercícios adaptados à sua rotina e de acordo com suas atividades de preferência, para realizar quando e onde quiser.</p><br><br><br><br>
      <a class="contentPromos-btn" href="#" type="submit" onclick="vai()">EU QUERO RESULTADOS</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `$( ".promoItemTreino-naoativo" ).css( "display", "none" );` - but you don't change the `clicked` data entry - so your code thinks it's still "clicked".  It's unclear what `$(this).data('clicked',` is for - seems you could do the same checking for `ativo` classes.

Comment: @freedomn-m sorry, i don't get it! how do i change the clicked data entry?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the `data` attribute value not being reset correctly when you hide the content.

However you can simplify and DRY your logic by using the same `class` on the 'card' and inner content elements. Then you can simply use JS to toggle the class on the clicked element, and use CSS rules to hide/show the inner content based on that class:

```js
const $cards = $('.card').on('click', e => {
  const $card = $(e.currentTarget);
  $card.toggleClass('ativo');
  $cards.not($card).removeClass('ativo');
});

$('a.contentPromos-btn').on('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  vai();
}); 

const vai = () => console.log('do something...');
```

```css
.contentPromos {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.card {
  height: 390px;
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f7afaf;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.card .content {
  display: none;
}

.card.ativo {
  height: 600px;
}

.card.ativo .content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="contentPromos">
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Plano Alimentar individualizado</h3>
    <p>Tenha consultas mensais com a nutricionista para montar planos alimentares de acordo com suas necessidades, preferências e objetivos. </p>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Tenha consultas mensais com a nutricionista para montar planos alimentares de acordo com suas necessidades, preferências e objetivos. </p><br><br>
      <a class="contentPromos-btn" href="#" type="submit">EU QUERO RESULTADOS</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Treinos personalizados</h3>
    <p>Tenha também planos de exercícios adaptados à sua rotina e de acordo com suas atividades de preferência, para realizar quando e onde quiser. </p>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Tenha também planos de exercícios adaptados à sua rotina e de acordo com suas atividades de preferência, para realizar quando e onde quiser.</p><br><br><br><br>
      <a class="contentPromos-btn" href="#" type="submit">EU QUERO RESULTADOS</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Note that the single event handler above will work for an infinite number of cards, so long as the `.card` and `.content` classes are applied correctly.

Finally, I removed the inline `onclick` attribute as it's not good practice. Attach your event handlers unobtrusively - exactly as you did for the card elements.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was having such a big problem with it and now its working well!